# Phrases like "Fifth Beatle" or "Fourth estate"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a term for phrases like [Fifth Beatle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Beatle) when there's four main Beatles, [fourth estate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fourth_estate) when there were originally only three estates, or Mongolia's [Third neighbor policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_neighbor_policy) when it only has two neighbours? Basically, the (n + 1)th item when there's only n items.

Comment: Eighth wonder of the world.

Comment: sixth sense, third eye

Comment: I'm looking for a term describing such phrases, not additional examples.

Comment: Which is why they're only comments and not answers I imagine.

Comment: Not to be a fifth wheel in this conversation, but a number of podunk (from a Manhattanite's perspective) satellite burgs often lay claim to being the *sixth borough* of New York City. And some of my more -- let's call them *zealously patriotic* -- acquaintances at times refer to Canada as the *fifty-first  state*.

Comment: It seems like there should be a term, similar to penultimate, meaning "one more than the last".

Comment: *supernumerary epithets*?

Comment: @DanBron Even Staten Island is barely considered part of New York City, despite actually being a borough. Which burgs are these?

Comment: @Matt: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough_(New_York_City)#Sixth_borough) suggests Yonkers, Mount Vernon, and Miami.

Answer (score 1):

[Supernumerary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supernumerary):

> "exceeding a regular or proper number."

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You might simply refer to the phrase, if you *must* refer to it, as: "honorary title". Ex:

"D'Artagnan is often spoken of with the *honorary title* of 'Fourth Musketeer'."